# Will newly added hosts in a Kafka cluster route data to the existing hosts in the cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm adding three new hosts to an existing three-host Kafka cluster. If I point my producers exclusively at those three new hosts, will the data be routed from those new hosts to the existing, original hosts in the cluster if all the topic's partitions are still balanced across the original three hosts?

I attempted to test this with our development six-node cluster. Hosts 4,5, and 6 had been reassigned all the topics partitions, and nothing was being processed on hosts 1,2, or 3. I used the console producer from host 1 to produce to a test topic whose partitions were balanced across hosts 4, 5, and 6, and everything looked right. I'm fairly certain this is a good test of my original question, but don't know all the ins and outs of the console producer.